# Is there a way to redeem Steam games from Steam keys while I'm not on my PC?

Tags: steam

I'm going to be away from the country (and from my PC) for a month. However, I'm going to receive some steam keys from a friend sometime next week, and I was wondering if there was a way for me to redeem steam games while I'm away.

I only have my mobile phone (Android) and tablet (iOS) while I'm away.

Is there a way for me to redeem steam games without a PC?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of, no.

Comment: You could install [TeamViewer](https://www.teamviewer.com/en/index.aspx) on your computer and phone to access your computer from your phone while you're away, then turn your computer off after you activate the keys.

Answer (score 5):

No.  The only official Valve software which allows you to redeem keys is the Steam PC (or Mac) client.

---

As for unofficial... the only reverse-engineering effort of Steam I know of is [SteamKit](https://github.com/SteamRE/SteamKit).  One of the lead developers [has stated](https://github.com/SteamRE/SteamKit/issues/68#issuecomment-51766445) SteamKit intentionally doesn't support redeeming keys because..

> There's no good reason to expose an API that could be potentially used to bruteforce CD keys.

Without that reverse engineering effort *(which takes an incredible amount of skill and knowledge to do, the vast majority of programmers would not be able to pull it off on their own)*, no regular developer can create a phone app which can redeem CD keys.

Answer (score 0):

Teamviewer would be a good possibility for accessing it, but that requires you leaving your PC on. My friend uses Teamviewer to open CS:GO cases in class.